# Исключение из правил HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, html

В общем, есть файл .htaccess
Содержание его следующее:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/http-bind
RewriteRule (.*) /http-bind [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

При обращении к левому *.html файлу вылазит ошибка 404
Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было обращаться к html файлам из корня, например к файлу подтверждения в панели вебмастера - без него нельзя подтвердить владения ресурсом.
В общем исключение из правил :)

И, если можно, подкиньте код чтобы Index.html грузился по умолчанию, а не index.php

Заранее большое спасибо :)

UPD: Поправочка, если поможет - файл htaccess от CMS Oxwall (oxwall.org, oxwall.su)

Answer (score 1):

а почему бы не сделать переадресацию с index.php на index.html

Поставь временно в индекс.пхп код с переадресацией на файл индекс.хтмл, когда подтвердишь владение просто уберешь.

Например так
<HTML> <HEAD> <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1; URL=/index.html"> </HEAD> <BODY> </BODY> </HTML>

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

И будет грузиться *.html

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/\.]*\.html$ # Исключает файлы *.html в корне сайта
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Теперь у вас должно получится подтвердить владение ресурсом.